# I want to write python program to cut a DNA sequence at an EcoRI restriction site and print the two fragments after cutting

Tags: python

Seq =
AAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTTTTGAATTCCCCCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGGGG

Restriction site = GAATTC

I want to cut the sequence at GA/ATTC

I tried split method in python but It does not cut at GA/ATTC.
Please help

Comment: Have you looked up the documentation on working with restriction enzymes in biopython? http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/Restriction.html#1.3

Comment: Nice documentation It really helped me. Thanks.

Comment: If you're able to do this after actually reading the documentation then please post a working example as an answer for others.

Comment: The obvious bare native Python `'AAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTTTTTGAATTCCCCCCCCCCCGGGGGGGGGGG'.split('GAATTC')` produces what I expect.

Comment: @tripleee, your solution would not reflect the "true biology" The restriction enzyme cuts within the recognized bases and the two resulting fragments would contain a part (different parts obviously) of the restriction site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Bio
from Bio.Seq import Seq
my_seq = Seq("aaaaaaaaaaatttttttttttgaattccccccccccggggggggggg")
from Bio.Restriction import *
print(EcoRI.search(my_seq))
print(EcoRI.catalyse(my_seq))
```

> Actully the EcoRI cuts the DNA after G in restriction site GAATTC.

Comment: Okay my apologies, optical analysis is one of the reasons why bioinformatics is so important. You can mark your post as 'accepted'.